# control button action with radio button java gui net beans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, radio-button

I am working on a Java project for College
I want to change a button action depends on radio button selection
so if user choose radio button1 and press the button Go it opens jframe2
and if user choose radio button2 and press the button Go it opens jframe3.

I am still a very beginner in Java plus if anyone could help me in further steps let me know :).

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a JRadioButton is selected, you can call the method [isSelected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()).

To check if a JButton has been clicked, you can add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to the button.

The example below adds an ActionListener to a jButton1 that will display either jframe2 or jframe3 based on which of the radio buttons are selected (given they're in the same ButtonGroup).

```
jButton1.addActionListener((event) -> {
    jframe2.setVisible(radioButton1.isSelected());
    jframe3.setVisible(radioButton2.isSelected());
});
```